# I am new with peercoin and confused is it mining or not [screenshot]

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, cgminer, peercoin

[image]

I am new in peercoin and trying first time mining of any currency just to see how it works.
I installed cgminer but there's an error

> Probing for an alive pool Network diff set to 91.5

like that but I am confused that is that are errors or not because its also saying

> stratum from pool 0 detect new block

can anyone explain me what's its going I mean working or not if not then why this error is coming if its working then meaning of these messages.

Thanks

Comment: What hardware do you want to use to mine? Cgminer hasn't GPU support from the 3.7.2 version

Comment: Not using any hardware just using my computer I just want to see how it works

Comment: i think cgminer decide not use your cpu because it's not efficent for sha (the algorithm behind peercoin). For seeing how it works i think you can try cpuminer

Comment: I think its for litecoin and bitcoin only

Comment: no, it isn't. bitcoin and peercoin share the same mining algorithm which is sha

Comment: If you have a graphics card you can use previous versoins of cgminer and have it mine with your GPU